# updating JSF component in different user page

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Can i update a jsf component in another users page.

For Example:
i have a Save Button (for User 1 - user1/user1.xhtml).

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" type="submit" update=":user2Form:datatable"/>
```

Datatable (for User2 - user2/user2.xhtml)

```
<p:dataTable id="datatable" ..../>
```

In my case both the page is in different folder, now how can i update the user2's datatable when the user1 save's a record.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean: "A user has two pages open and wants to update one from inside another" then AFAIK due to security reasons this is not possible.

Maybe another solution would be to use PrimeFaces push. This way you can send updates from the server to the client.